# How can I get Google to display a yellow "Ad" icon for my site using AdWords?

Tags: google-search, search-results, google-ads

When we search for our website using Google Search, how can we show our site at the top of search results with a yellow `Ad` icon like below:

[image]

Is this possible using AdWords?

Answer (score 3):

You have to advertise on your own branded search terms. Check Search console for the keywords people most often use to reach your site and add them to your AdWords list.